# Add dots if string has more than 10 words

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return a preview of my texts by getting the first 10 words.

```
concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(q.value, ' ', 10), '...') AS preview
```

this works great when the string is long. But it should not be added when the string is shorter (because there is nothing more).

Is it possible to do this with 100% mysql?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when substring_index(q.value, ' ', 10) = q.value
             then q.value
             else concat(substring_index(q.value, ' ', 10), '...')
        end)
```